# Calculating the sum of items in a ListBox- Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

this is my first time posting on here. I'm having some difficulty with a program for a class I'm taking. I need to get the miles and gallons then calculate the MPG for each entry. I have this part figured out. What I can't seem to get is the totals at the bottom. I need to add the sum of all the items in each ListBox and calculate the total MPG each time the button is clicked. Here's my code so far.

```
Public Class MilesPerGallon
    Private Sub calculateMPGButton_Click(sender As System.Object,
        ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles calculateMPGButton.Click

        Dim miles As Double ' miles driven
        Dim gallons As Double ' gallons used
        Dim totalMiles As Double ' total miles driven
        Dim totalGallons As Double ' total gallons used
        Dim counter As Integer

        miles = milesDrivenTextBox.Text ' get the miles driven
        gallons = gallonsUsedTextBox.Text ' get the gallons used

        If milesDrivenTextBox.Text <> String.Empty Then
            ' add miles to the end of the milesListBox
            milesListBox.Items.Add(milesDrivenTextBox.Text)
            milesDrivenTextBox.Clear() ' clears the milesDrivenTextBox
        End If

        If gallonsUsedTextBox.Text = 0 Then
            ' do not divide by 0 and alert 0
            gallonsUsedTextBox.Text = "Cannot equal 0"
        End If

        If gallonsUsedTextBox.Text > 0 Then
            ' add gallons to the end of the gallonsListBox
            gallonsListBox.Items.Add(gallonsUsedTextBox.Text)
            mpgListBox.Items.Add(String.Format("{0:F}", miles / gallons))
            gallonsUsedTextBox.Clear() ' clears the gallonsUsedTextBox
        End If

        totalMiles = 0
        totalGallons = 0
        counter = 0

        Do While totalMiles < milesListBox.Items.Count
            miles = milesListBox.Items(totalMiles)
            totalMiles += miles
            counter += 1

            Do While totalGallons < gallonsListBox.Items.Count
                gallons = gallonsListBox.Items(totalGallons)
                totalGallons += gallons
                counter += 1
            Loop
        Loop
        If totalMiles <> 0 Then


            totalResultsLabel.Text = "Total miles driven: " & totalMiles & vbCrLf &
                "Total gallons used: " & totalGallons & vbCrLf & "Total MPG: " &
                String.Format("{0:F}", totalMiles / totalGallons)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `while` loop conditions are incorrect since you are comparing the `ListBox.Items.Count` with the total sum. I would use `Linq` instead because it's much more readable:

```
Dim totalMiles As Int32 = milesListBox.Items.Cast(Of Int32)().Sum()
Dim totalGallons As Int32 = gallonsListBox.Items.Cast(Of Int32)().Sum()
```

Comment: Where does that go in the code? Pardon my ignorance, I've only been learning VB for about two weeks. Thanks again.